# Reading tokens from file (complicated)

Tags: c++, string, parsing, stringstream

I have a basic tokenization structure/algorithm in place. It's pretty complicated, and I hope I can clarify it simply enough to enlighten you about the "flaw" in my design.

class ParserState

```
// bool functions return false if getline() or stream extraction '>>' fails
static bool nextLine(); // reads and tokenizes next line from file and puts it in m_buffer
static bool nextToken(); // gets next token from m_buffer, via fetchToken(), and puts it in m_token
static bool fetchToken( std::string &token ); // procures next token from file/buffer

static size_t m_lineNumber;
static std::ifstream m_fstream;
static std::string m_buffer;
static std::string m_token;
```

The reason for this setup is being able to report the line number if a syntax error occurs. Depending on the phase/state of the parser, differend things happen in my program, and subclasses of this ParserState use `m_token` and `nextToken` to continue.  `fetchToken` calls `nextLine` if `m_buffer` is empty, and puts the next token in its argument:

```
istringstream stream;

do // read new line until valid token can be extracted
{
    Debug(5) << "m_buffer contains: " << m_buffer << "\n";
    stream.str( m_buffer );

    if( stream >> token )
    {
        Debug(5) << "Token extracted: " << token << "\n";
        m_token = token;
        return true; // return when token found
    }
    stream.clear();
} while( nextLine() );
// if no tokens can be extracted from the whole file, return false
return false;
```

The problem is that the token removed from m_buffer isn't removed, and the same token gets read with every call to `nextToken()`. The problem is that `m_buffer` can be modified, thus the call to `istringstream::str` in the loop. But this is the cause of my issue, and as far as I can see, it can't be worked around, hence my question: How can I let `stream >> token` remove something from the string pointed to internally by the stringstream? Perhaps I need to *not* use a `stringstream`, but something more elementary in this situation (like find first whitespace and cut the first token from the string)?

Thanks a billion!

PS: any suggestions altering my function/class structure are ok as long as they allow line numbers to be kept track of (so no full file read into `m_buffer` and a class member `istringstream`, which is what I had before I wanted line number error reporting).

Comment: Why are all these members `static`?

Comment: @Oli: all subclasses need to access the same data (the subclasses parse different parts/words of the file, so if one state reads a token, the next state needs to read the next token, not some state-specific thing, hence static=the same for all subclasses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply make `m_buffer` an `std::istringstream` instead of a `std::string`? You would remove a temporary variable as well as get the desired effect. Whenever you change `m_buffer` in statements such as

```
m_buffer = ...
```

write this instead:

```
m_buffer.str(...);
```

Comment: Then I would have to change my `getline( m_fstream, m_buffer )` by something else right? Because that's really the only reason I chose a string. I'll try this and let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you would have to use a string temporary there or use `std::istreambuf_iterator` and `std::ostreambuf_iterator`, with a variant of `std::copy()` that takes an optional delimiter.

Comment: Well, I converted the whole thing to use a `stringstream m_buffer` instead of a `string` and I use stream operators to insert and extract tokens. Works great, thanks for showing me the part I missed :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid reading the same token multiple times I think you have to get the position in `stream` using `tellg` and then restore it using `seekg` (these methods are described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/tellg/)). However using `std::istringstream` looks as an overkill for me here. I would rather work with `m_buffer` directly.

Comment: That's my problem with stringstream, it's yet another buffer, and a string can do everything I need. tellg will also allow me to point to the erronous token in the error message, which is a nice side effect. I'll look into this!

Answer (score 0):

The usual scheme for handling line-number reporting is to read lines one at time, as you have, incrementing a the line count, and then as your tokenizer starts to build a token, it takes a snapshot of the line number and stores it into the token data structure (typically containing the line number, token type, and token value if any).

This decouples line-reading from token building without losing the line number.  It also means you can have lots of tokens, they can all have line numbers (including different ones), a token can start on one line and and finish on another, etc.